# What does the $dx$ mean in the notation for the indefinite integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I am following N. Piskunov's book for Integral calculus. The indefinite integral is introduced in the notation  $\int f(x) dx$ without explaining the meaning of dx. At first I thought it was mere notation to indicate what variable we are integrating in reference to.

But when attempting integration by substitution, we can clearly treat $dx$ as a a part of the expression, and not just notation. For example, $$\int f'(x)/f(x) dx $$ and $$t=f(x)$$
then $$dt/dx = f'(x)$$ and then we can substitute in dx to get the answer and it works.

Why can we treat dx like this in order to get results? Is it not only supposed to indicate the reference variable of integration.

Edit: I realised my question was too vague. I understand how the differential operator works and that dx, dy etc can be used algebraically. But what I'm confused about is what the expression $f(x)dx$ means if $dx$ does not just notation. And then the next obvious question is what the integral operator $\int$ doing to it such that it results in the antiderivative of $f(x).$

Comment: Well, you can $\textit{can}$ view it as just notation. U substitution is just the reverse of the chain rule, so you’re just breaking taking an anti derivative down into steps. You use the notation $dx$ and $dt/dx$, and change the variable of integration so that you don’t get bogged down in a notational quagmire. 

You could also not view it as notation, and look into differential forms. Then these really are the “natural objects to integrate” and $dx$ has a real meaning. This is probably beyond the scope of learning integral calculus though and not worth the bother at the moment

Comment: When we interpret it with strictly Riemann integration, dx is the differential length of the rectangles of the limit of the Riemann sum. When you do substitutions, the differential length changes so you change stuff accordingly. Manipulation is further justified with nonstandard analysis, which provides a rigorous backbone for these manipulations.

Comment: For any approximating rectangle for the area between the graph and the axis we have an area of the form $f(x_0)\Delta x$. As $\Delta x$ approaches zero we call it $dx$. This is the motivation for defining integrals as a certain limit on a Reimann sum.

Answer (score 1):

A definite integral can be defined as the limit of a Riemann sum.

$$\int_a^b f(x) ~dx = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \sum_{k=0}^{N - 1} f(x_k) \Delta x$$

where $N = \lfloor \frac{b-a}{\Delta x} \rfloor$ is the number of sub-intervals, and $x_k \in [ a + k\Delta x, a + (k + 1)\Delta x]$ is arbitrarily selected within each sub-interval.

The summand represents the area of a rectangle, with a height ($y$) of $f(x_k)$ and a width of $\Delta x$.

Notationally, you can think of $\int$ as a replacement for $\sum$, and $dx$ as a replacement for $\Delta x$.  Just spelling variants of the letters S (for sum) and D (for difference).

---

A similar argument applies to the “fraction” notation for derivatives.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y := f(x + \Delta x) - f(x)}{\Delta x}$$

As $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ approach 0, we call them $dx$ and $dy$.